# Rebind listnav plugin using AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using listnav plugin [jQuery listnav](https://github.com/esteinborn/jquery-listnav) to filter my data result. I've created a directive to call listnav() method.

When I bind the ng-repeat again with new results (letter A in the sample), the plugin create another navigation bar.

Please, take a look my sample in http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbwVWZ?editors=101

```
<div style="height: 50px"></div>  

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">        
    <input type="button" ng-click="send()" value="Load letter A"></input>
    <hr>    
    <ul id="demoOne" class="demo" listnav>
        <li ng-repeat="i in items" ng-bind="i.name"></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

```
$(function(){
//$('#demoOne').listnav();

$('.demo a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
});

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    var m = [
        {name: "411 Services"},
        {name: "Accountants"},
        {name: "Acupuncture"},
        {name: "Human Resource Consultants"},
        {name: "Importers"},
        {name: "Industrial - Equipment &amp; Supplies (Wholesale)"},
        {name: "Investments"},
        {name: "Janitor Service"},
        {name: "Jewelers (Wholesale)"},
        {name: "Jewelers - Retail"},
        {name: "Restaurants - Barbecue"},
        {name: "Roofing - Materials"},
        {name: "Roofing - Service Consultants"},
        {name: "Sand &amp; Gravel (Wholesale)"},
        {name: "School Supplies (Wholesale)"},
        {name: "Schools &amp; Educational Services"},
        {name: "Schools - Nursery &amp; Kindergarten Academic"},
        {name: "Vacuum Cleaners - Household - Dealers"},
        {name: "Vending Machines"},
        {name: "Ventilating Systems - Cleaning"},
        {name: "Wallpapers &amp; Wallcoverings - Installation"},
        {name: "Yoga Instruction"},
        {name: "Youth Organizations &amp; Centers"},
        {name: "Zilch"}
    ];

    $scope.items = m;

    $scope.send = function(){
        var n = [            
            {name: "Accountants"},
            {name: "Acupuncture"}
        ];            

        $scope.items = n;
        $scope.loadNav();
    };   
}

myApp.directive('listnav', function($timeout){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        link: function($scope, elem, attrs){            

            $scope.loadNav = function(){
                $timeout(function(){
                    $(elem).listnav();
                });
            };

            $scope.loadNav();
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling your `loadNav()` function again on your call to `send()`.

```
$scope.send = function(){
    var n = [            
        {name: "Accountants"},
        {name: "Acupuncture"}
    ];            

    $scope.items = n;
    //$scope.loadNav(); // this change
};
```

[Codepen update](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXRpxV?editors=101)

**Edit based on comment**

You could remove the previous one;

```
$scope.send = function(){
    var n = [            
        {name: "Accountants"},
        {name: "Acupuncture"}
    ];            

    $scope.items = n;
    $(".listNav").remove(); // added this
    $scope.loadNav();
};
```

[Codepen update](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doEJOE?editors=101)

Comment: This way the bar doesn't update and keeps showing wrong counts and highligth letters.

Comment: Almost there! The letter N is counting "No matching entries" and option "All" increase each click. I'm searching for a fix. Thanks for the idea of .remove().

Comment: I fixed it temporarily changing the deafult option noMatchText: ''